# How to convert a fastai Image to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, fast-ai

I have an image in fastai format:

```
type(im)
```

the result is:

`fastai.vision.image.Image`

However, I need to use cv2 to manipulate the image by the following code

```
cv2.resize(im, (size,size), interpolation=interpolation)
```

When argument of `im` was under fastai image format, an error occured:
`TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'`

Therefore, the fastai image should be converted to np.array format. How can I do it?

I am using fastai v1.0.61, which is the default setting of Google's Colab.

Comment: try `cv_img = image2np(im)` -  I took from [here](https://fastai1.fast.ai/vision.image.html#image2np). it takes a tensor image and converts to ndarray (which an open-cv image is)

Comment: Seems that image2np won't work. The input should be a torch.Tensor,  not a fastai Image. If you look at the source code, the method uses `image.cpu().permute(1,2,0).numpy()`, but fastai image cannot do this: `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'permute'`.

Comment: perhaps file a bug report with fast.ai because if their docs don't say (I did a little googling), it's either a missing feature, or their docs need work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **numpy.array(z), (where z type is fastai.torch_core.TensorImage),** you will get the numpy array for the required image. Hope this is helpful for you.